# How to replace electric tailgate lift on Volvo XC 60 2012?

Tags: maintenance, volvo, trunk, xc60

My volvo xc60 has been having issues with the trunk and the lift gate. 
We got the lift gate to come off with a flat head screwdriver but the "electrical" part is still connected. 
I'm wondering what part I would need for this repair and how much it would cost. If it is difficult to explain how to complete this repair with words a video would help as well. 
Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2g74.jpg

Any help is greatly appreciated, 
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!